# How do I install TP-Link network drivers?

Tags: networking, drivers

I have a TP-Link Archer T4U Plus connected to my computer. This exact model doesn't have drivers for Linux, but I heard that the Archer T4U V3 drivers work just fine for the model I have. I used a flash drive to transfer the files to my computer, but in the instructions, to install the drivers, I need to install things using apt-get. How can I install something without internet to get internet?

Comment: Hmm… IDK if this is possible for you, but usually you can download the .deb of whatever you’re trying to install, and install the deb file with sudo dpkg -i myfile.deb

Comment: IF they work as you say you can use any alternative temporary internet connection like USB tethering that any current phone does in order to install what it needs from the online repositories. That said, when asking here, it's preferable to post a proper question in which the hardware is identified (brand/model aren't relevant; revision/version helps but not always and in any case it should be the potential helpers job to find out information, it's *your* job to provide it from the start) so the experts here can guide you towards the best drivers available and how to install them.

Comment: The manufacturer's published drivers are often NOT the best option. Sometimes there's a package already in the repos that needs installation with APT and it's done (best case scenario) or need to be compiled from GIT with DKMS (second best option, one time installation) or without (need reinstalling after any kernel upgrade).